# jQuery TextExt - Ajax autocomplete issue with specifying the url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-textext

I am using the [jQuery TextExt plugin](http://textextjs.com/manual/examples/ajax-with-filter-tags-and-autocomplete.html) for `autocomplete`, and I got no problem using its example json url which is data.json. But when I use my own url, which is something like the following:

```
$('#textarea').textext({
    plugins : 'autocomplete filter tags ajax',
    ajax : {
        url :'/users/userApi.do?id=10&scopeType=all&username=user@this.com&password=pass',
        dataType : 'json',
        cacheResults : true
    }
});
```

It does not work!!

The data which is returned from this url is not pre populated that is, it populates the data based on the id and scopeType and return the right JSON format. (When I try it by itself on the browser and run, I can see the correct result on the screen).

Should the JSON data be always pre populated in this example?

I am not experienced using autocomplete, so please help me out here or if there is a better way for doing this, would be great if you can share.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the cacheResults option and make sure you are returning an array of results in JSON format. cacheResults for me didn't work as my data was dynamic.

Example I have working below:

```
$('#marketingkeywords')
    .textext({
        plugins : 'autocomplete tags ajax',
        ajax : {
            url : '/ajax/getkeywords.php',
            dataType : 'json',
            cacheResults : false
        },
        autocomplete : {
            enabled : true,
    dropdown : {
                position : 'above',
                maxHeight : '60px'
            }
        }
    })
;
```

Also make sure your URL is returning the data using something like the network panel in Chrome (response tab).
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network

Answer (score 0):

i think that u make some silly mistake regarding including files like as miss plugin js try to add plugin ajax file as

```
<script src="js/textext.core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
<script src="js/textext.plugin.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
<script src="js/textext.plugin.suggestions.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/textext.plugin.ajax.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

and then try as above